# Why can't this ansible role (geerlinguy.postgresql) find the variables?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have the following Ansible Playbook:

```
- hosts: vdtreportlive
  vars_files:
    - ./vars/postgresql.yml
    - ./vars/postgresql_report.yml
  roles:
    - role: geerlingguy.postgresql
```

When I run this, I get this error: `ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'postgresql_user'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.`

However, if I run this modified playbook to check for the presence of the variable, I get the expected result.

```
- hosts: vdtreportlive
  vars_files:
    - ./vars/postgresql.yml
    - ./vars/postgresql_report.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Print the value of variable postgresql_user
      debug:
        msg: "{{ postgresql_user }} "
```

This results in

```
ok: [vdtreportlive] => {
    "msg": "postgres "
}
```

Why can't the role find the variable when the task can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is about the [postgresql_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_user_module.html#ansible-collections-community-postgresql-postgresql-user-module) **module**, whereas you are referring to `postgresql_user` as a variable.

You have to make sure that this module is installed, it is not part of Ansible core.  Quoting the docs:

> It is not included in ansible-core. To check whether it is installed, run `ansible-galaxy collection list`

> To install it, use: `ansible-galaxy collection install community.postgresql`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue. Since the repository for geerlingguy.postgresql states that there are "No special requirements" and "None." under Dependencies, I think this is an error in their documentation.

Comment: @Shade it wouldn't be any different if you were using Python, Perl, Php etc.........

Comment: @Squashman I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. What wouldn't be any different and how would I be using other programming languages instead of ansible?

Comment: What I am saying is that for just about any utility or programming language there is a base or core install of it.  Any additional modules you need for that programming language or utility need to be installed.  That is how Python, PHP, PERL, Ansible, etc.......works.

Comment: Sure. But if a project states that there are no dependencies on any additional modules I would generally expect that to be the case. And I don't seem to be the only one. https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-postgresql/issues/256